# Listing several tables into one table in MS Access (transpose)

Tags: sql, ms-access, transpose

This question might seem generic, but it's rather complicated.

Let's start with the basics of software:
MS Access 2016
MS SQL ver. 17.7
DAQFactory 17.1

DAQFactory is a SCADA software, which I use to measure and store data from multiple temperature sensors. I use an "Export Set" to export the sensor data to my MSSQL Database. I sample the sensor data once a minute, generating 1 row of sensor data. I've set it up to create a new table for each sample (because I only need to sample 10 times/from 1 to 10 minutes, and that way I don't need to change the names of my tables all the time).

I have 6 temperature sensors, that DAQFactory export in a format like this:

[image: Table view from MS SQL, showing the raw data from DAQFactory, just a sample with six temperature sensors]

The MS SQL database is simply just a carrier/channel for my data to go from DAQFactory to MS Access, and therefore I do not have any problems with the database.

This is a School Project and I'm in over my head. The client I'm making the software package for wants to collect his data in a report with other types of data. Therefore I need to put the sensor data into a form like this:

[image: Table view from the report (the end-result)]

I use MS Access to create the report and to collect data from my database. I've tried several types of queries, but i can't get it to work like I want.

The problem is that the table in the database and in the report have the opposite placement of row and columns and I'm not able to switch it in a query in Access (also called a transpose).

**I've looked at some of these solutions:**

https://access-programmers.co.uk/forums/showthread.php?t=169794

[converting column names to use as row fields in Access](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/20227458/converting-column-names-to-use-as-row-fields-in-access)

[Access - transpose some column data into row records](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/37524833/access-transpose-some-column-data-into-row-records)

JOIN functions

PIVOT functions

But I can't get it to work.

**Export sets:**

All my export sets include the same columns:

[TheTime],
[T_01],
[T_02],
[T_03],
[T_04],
[T_05],
[T_06]

The export sets are called:
dbo.Temp_1min
dbo.Temp_2min
dbo.Temp_3min
dbo.Temp_4min
and so on up to 10.

When importing this to Access, [TheTime] becomes the primary key, and all samples that are recorded, are recorded on the exact same second, so this is naturally the ID of the tables.

Here is the code I'm using to show my data. I am using the "Totals: Last" so that the only thing that shows in my table is the last value from each table and sensor. Excuse the code, it's formatted in Norwegian but the only difference is "SisteAv" which means "LastOf" e.g the "Totals: Last" function.

**Code to get the last value from the "dbo_Temp_1min" table, this query is called "Temp_Samples1":**

```
SELECT Last(dbo_Temp_1min.TheTime) AS SisteAvTheTime, Last(dbo_Temp_1min.T_01) AS SisteAvT_01, Last(dbo_Temp_1min.T_02) AS SisteAvT_02, Last(dbo_Temp_1min.T_03) AS SisteAvT_03, Last(dbo_Temp_1min.T_04) AS SisteAvT_04, Last(dbo_Temp_1min.T_05) AS SisteAvT_05, Last(dbo_Temp_1min.T_06) AS SisteAvT_06
FROM dbo_Temp_1min;
```

**Code to put several tables into one:**

```
SELECT [SisteAvTheTime], [SisteAvT_01], [SisteAvT_02], [SisteAvT_03], [SisteAvT_04], [SisteAvT_05], [SisteAvT_06] 
FROM Temp_Samples1

UNION

SELECT [SisteAvTheTime], [SisteAvT_01], [SisteAvT_02], [SisteAvT_03], [SisteAvT_04], [SisteAvT_05], [SisteAvT_06] 
FROM Temp_Samples2;
```

This is the current result I am getting and the column and rows are opposite of what I need:

[image: This is the current result I am getting, and as you can see, the column and rows are opposite of what I need for my report (as shown in the first picture)]

To clarify what I need:

1)The first column to list the names of all the temperature sensors (T_01, T_02, T_03 etc.).

2) The second column to list the last row of sensor data from table 1 (dbo.Temp_1min).

3) The third column to list the last row of sensor data from table 2 (dbo.Temp_2min)

4) The fourth column to list the last row of sensor data from table 3 (dbo.Temp_3min)

etc...

The column "TheTime" is not relevant for the end result and should be hidden, since the time depends on the names on the tables (1min, 2min, 3min etc.)

As per request the data contained in MS SQL database for [dbo.Temp_1min]:

```
TheTime                 T_01          T_02          T_03          T_04          T_05          T_06
----------------------- ------------- ------------- ------------- ------------- ------------- -------------
2018-05-24 15:18:37.000 -0,080911     -0,051013     0,090363      0,034291      -0,096702     -0,016438
2018-05-25 15:04:22.010 0,095227      0,021559      -0,099226     -0,003178     0,099815      -0,015269
2018-05-25 15:04:23.003 0,095226      0,021562      -0,099226     -0,003181     0,099815      -0,015265
2018-05-25 20:06:17.000 0,061521      0,072766      -0,075043     -0,058863     0,085937      0,042978
2018-05-25 20:12:47.000 60,50084      73,64336      -74,18618     -59,89857     85,27211      44,13688
2018-05-25 20:12:47.000 60,50084      73,66345      -74,16626     -59,92236     85,25659      44,16353
2018-05-25 20:06:17.000 0,061521      0,072787      -0,075024     -0,058887     0,085922      0,043005
2018-05-25 20:10:40.003 60,83407      73,37933      -74,46661     -59,5624      85,49031      43,7604
2018-05-25 20:10:40.003 60,83407      73,37933      -74,44677     -59,58627     85,47488      43,78712
2018-05-25 20:23:07.003 58,85883      75,03191      -72,77819     -61,54791     84,16943      45,98995
```

(10 rows affected)

Comment: I am confused, isn't the first picture the raw data, not the desired output? Post sample raw data as a table, not an image. Do the same for desired result.

Comment: I don't know how to post a table, but I've updated my question to include the raw data, copied from MS SQL in "Result To Text (Ctrl + T)" format. If you want it in another format, please clarify how I can provide that.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

UNION query is limited to 50 SELECT lines. You have 10 tables and 6 sensors which means 60 SELECT lines. If there were less of either, a single UNION could merge the tables and then a CROSSTAB could pivot the data. Instead, do 10 UNION queries and JOIN them. Here is example of first UNION.

```
SELECT TOP 1 TheTime, T_01 AS Min1, "T01" AS Sensor, "1Min" AS Source FROM Temp_1min ORDER BY TheTime DESC
UNION (SELECT TOP 1 TheTime, T_02, "T02", "1Min" FROM Temp_1min ORDER BY TheTime DESC)
UNION (SELECT TOP 1 TheTime, T_03, "T03", "1Min" FROM Temp_1min ORDER BY TheTime DESC)
UNION (SELECT TOP 1 TheTime, T_04, "T04", "1Min" FROM Temp_1min ORDER BY TheTime DESC)
UNION (SELECT TOP 1 TheTime, T_05, "T05", "1Min" FROM Temp_1min ORDER BY TheTime DESC)
UNION (SELECT TOP 1 TheTime, T_06, "T06", "1Min" FROM Temp_1min ORDER BY TheTime DESC);
```

Now pick one of the queries to be the 'master' and join the other 9 to it. Here is example with only 2 queries.

```
SELECT [Q1].Sensor, [Q1].Min1, [Q2].Min2
FROM Q2 INNER JOIN Q1 ON [Q2].Sensor = [Q1].Sensor
ORDER BY [Q1].Sensor;
```

The output (used same sample data for both tables):

```
Sensor   Min1       Min2
T01    58.85883   58.85883
T02    75.03191   75.03191
T03   -72.77819  -72.77819
T04   -61.54791  -61.54791
T05    84.16943   84.16943
T06    45.98995   45.98995
```

If this is too unmanageable and/or performs so slowly as to be impractical, only other approach would be with VBA. See example of similar requirement in https://www.access-programmers.co.uk/forums/showthread.php?t=299864.

Comment: Yes, thank you!

I customized my code to your suggestion and it worked. Now that I know the queries work as expected, I have altered all my query names to make it easy-to-follow. I now have 10 queries that's joined in one INNER JOIN query